# Android push notification developer

Tags: android, push-notification

Do we need a developer account to create an api project?

For example when I try to create the api project, I used my gmail (not developer)
but the push notification did not work so I ask if it is maybe the problem?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can try any gmail account. It's not strict requirenment to use android developer account.

If you provide us with more information about how you configure your project in Dev Console I will try to help you :)

Comment: Thanks @Tpec1j its works fine now, when I delete the project and recreate it